# SQL Server - SUM and comma-separated values using GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables:

NDEvent:

```
EventId  EndTime       
33       2020-10-23 15:00:00.000
33       2020-10-23 15:00:00.000
35       2020-10-21 03:30:00.000
35       2020-10-24 15:00:00.000
35       2020-10-25 15:00:00.000
34       2020-10-23 15:00:00.000
```

EventAppointment:

```
Id DocId  EventId Amount
1  7647    34     10.00
2  7647    34     10.00
3  28531   33     20.00
4  7647    35     20.00
5  7647    35     100.00
6  7647    35     200.00
```

And I want result to be like this:

```
DocId  EventId  Amount  Id
7647    34      20.00   1,2
28531   33      20.00   3
7647    35      320.00  4,5,6
```

What I have tried is:

```
select e.Amount,e.DoctorId,e.EventId,
    Id= STUFF(    
     (SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + CAST(e.Id as nvarchar(max))   
     from NDEvent nd 
     inner join EventAppointment e on nd.Id = e.EventId
     where 
     GETDATE() > nd.EndTime
     GROUP BY 
     e.Amount,e.DoctorId,e.EventId,e.Id
      FOR XML PATH(''))    
        , 1, 1, ''    
    ) 
    from NDEvent nd 
    inner join EventAppointment e on nd.Id = e.EventId
    where 
    GETDATE() > nd.EndTime
    GROUP BY 
    e.Amount,e.DoctorId,e.EventId
```

But it is not giving expected result.

Could anyone help with this query? Or point me to a right direction? Thank you.

Comment: *"But it is not giving expected result."* To start with you don't have  a `SUM` in there. You can't get the sum of something without a `SUM`.

Comment: Did you have a look at STRING_AGG? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @RandomUser if you are going to provide links to off site resources on Stack Overflow, please do ensure they are in English.

Comment: My apologies. I edited the link, but MSDN tries really hard to display its content in local language.

Comment: @Larnu using `SUM` also it is not giving expected output as it is giving data with all ids if I use `SUM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like yo need to `NDEvent` table here at all (though I include it in the sample data). Just `SUM` and `STRING_AGG` against `EventAppointment`:

```sql
USE Sandbox
GO

WITH NDEvent AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(33,CONVERT(datetime,'2020-10-23T15:00:00.000')),
                (33,CONVERT(datetime,'2020-10-23T15:00:00.000')),
                (35,CONVERT(datetime,'2020-10-21T03:30:00.000')),
                (35,CONVERT(datetime,'2020-10-24T15:00:00.000')),
                (35,CONVERT(datetime,'2020-10-25T15:00:00.000')),
                (34,CONVERT(datetime,'2020-10-23T15:00:00.000')))V(EventID,EndTime)),
EventAppointment AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,7647 ,34,10.00),
                (2,7647 ,34,10.00),
                (3,28531,33,20.00),
                (4,7647 ,35,20.00),
                (5,7647 ,35,100.00),
                (6,7647 ,35,200.00))V(Id,DocId, EventID, Amount))
SELECT DocID,
       EventID,
       SUM(Amount) AS Amount,
       STRING_AGG(Id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Id) AS IDs
FROM EventAppointment EA
GROUP BY DocId,
         EventID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be used in other data.

```
 WITH Table1 AS(
    SELECT EventId FROM NDEvent
    GROUP BY EventId
    ),
    Table2 AS(
        SELECT e.DocId,e.EventId,e.Amount,
        STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + CAST(ee.Id as nvarchar) 
            FROM EventAppointment ee
            where ee.EventId = e.EventId
            GROUP BY ee.EventId,ee.Id
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Id
        FROM Table1 t
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EventAppointment e ON t.EventId = e.EventId
    )
    SELECT DocId,EventId,SUM(Amount) AS Amount,Id FROM Table2
    GROUP BY DocId,EventId,Id
```

Comment: Sorry @Adnan but it's not giving the result which I want. :)